# Which graphical technologies were used for creating interface for Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, visual-studio-2013

Please, tell me which graphical subsystem for rendering user interfaces (WPF or WinRT, ...) were used for creating interface for Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @shambulator: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Actually, it does *not* say that questions on SO are exclusively restricted to programming itself, as in, how to write some specific source code. Also, while the C# tag is certainly inappropriate, I consider it questionable to label this question as "not about programming" when it asks about a UI toolkit.

Comment: Also I guess the reason for the question is to know which framework/engine can handle a complex UI interface like VS2013.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper OK, I agree my comment is badly phrased, but I stand by the close vote. No, the question might not be about a piece of source code, but it's not about a problem either (*"a specific programming problem", "a software algorithm", "software tools commonly used by programmers", "practical, answerable problems ... unique to software development"*) and is of no value (IMO) to anyone who comes along later. Note the list of criteria for being off-topic focuses on the assumption that the question is about a *problem*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2013 runs on WPF.

UI snooping can prove this.
Also WinRT is not an option because VS2013 runs on Non-WinRT platforms too.

Comment: Maybe it is WPF but not sure on the reason you give? MFC and WinForms are non WINRT technologies too...

Comment: Use a tool like snoop on VS2013 itself. It exposes it uses System.Windows.* like styles and all. Although MFC and WinForms... MS would not itself be doing a favour. At least not since WPF can be considered stable.

Comment: @Anthony, I think ZoolWay was referring to options that asker has provided in his question.

Comment: There are also a lot of "older" windows and controls that make use of .NET Winforms and even older forms that are built in MFC or ActiveX. All recent development has been done in WPF.